# Как использовать libclang?

Tags: c++, clang

Как этим вообще можно пользоваться? Или разработчики специально сделали все, чтобы их поделием пользовались как можно меньше? Использую Linux Mint 17. Устанавливаю `apt-get install clang-3.5 clang-3.5-dev llvm-3.5 llvm-3.5-dev` и все предлагаемые зависимости. Создаю проект, в pro-файле пишу: `LIBS += -lclang`, в cpp: `#include <clang-c/Index.h>`. Пытаюсь скомпилировать, и хрен вам. Не найден файл `"clang-c/Index.h"`. Идем в `/usr/lib/include/llvm-3.5/clang-c` - вот он родимый, лежит себе. Я и пути в pro-файл добавлял до него и чего я только не делал, не видится это файл.

Comment: Запускай сборку так `make VERBOSE=1 ycm_core"`, что выведет?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 0):

Либо флаг -I/usr/include/llvm-3.5 или в тексте "#include llvm-3.5/clang-c/index.h"

Comment: Находит файл только если гвоздями прибить полный путь к нему в cpp' шнике